# Celery AsyncResult get hostname

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have a celery set up that uses two different servers to process tasks. I'm trying to figure out the best way to match which server the task completed on. I looked through the docs and didn't see anything about retrieving the hostname from an AsyncResult.

Any input on this matter is appreciated. Another option I was thinking of trying is simply putting the hostname within each celery config, although this method is not desired as it is one more thing to remember to do.

Answer (score 5):

A possible workaround is returning the hostname with task return value

```
from celery import current_task

@celery.task
def hello(x, y):
  return dict(hostname=current_task.request.hostname, result='hello')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is the approach that I ended up using. I forgot to update this post. The main issue I was bringing up is that I feel that the hostname is a valuable piece of information that should be included as a gimme in each response.